# Error inflating custom TextView in Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-inflate

I have searched for hours now for a solution but can't find one. I am trying to create a custom TextView which animates the values if it is numbers. However, I get an exception even before it starts the first value. I hope you can help.

Here is my code:

```
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AnimatedValueTextView extends TextView {
    private static final int DURATION = 900;
    private float actualValue;
    private ValueAnimator animator;

    public AnimatedValueTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public AnimatedValueTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public AnimatedValueTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }


    private void init()
    {
        actualValue = 0;
        animator = new ValueAnimator();

        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                setText(valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue().toString());
                actualValue = (Float)valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            }
        });

        animator.setDuration(DURATION);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter) {
        super.onTextChanged(text, start, lengthBefore, lengthAfter);

        boolean validValue = true;
        float newValue = 0;

        try {
            newValue = Float.parseFloat(this.getText().toString());
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            validValue = false;
        }

        if(validValue)
        {
            if(animator == null)
            {
                init();
            }

            animator.cancel();
            animator.setFloatValues(actualValue, newValue);
            animator.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

And my XML

```
<com.---.-------.AnimatedValueTextView
            android:id="@+id/actualPressure"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/FunkyTextBig"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:text="1043"/>
```

And the LogCat

```
01-16 09:55:14.954    5085-5085/com.---.----- E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class com.---.-----.AnimatedValueTextView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at com.---.-----.ForecastFragment.onCreateView(ForecastFragment.java:70)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:474)
            at android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:167)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:477)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at com.---.-----.ForecastFragment.onCreateView(ForecastFragment.java:70)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:474)
            at android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:167)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:477)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
            at java.lang.RealToString.floatToString(RealToString.java:126)
            at java.lang.Float.toString(Float.java:322)
            at java.lang.Float.toString(Float.java:310)
```

And the  style used:

```
<style name="FunkyTextBig" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">#eaf1f7</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:shadowRadius">13</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">45sp</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDy">0</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FunkyTextMedium" parent="@style/FunkyTextBig">
        <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: which version of android has the device where you are testing it ?

Comment: It is version 4.3 and I am developing for 4.0.4 and newer

Comment: could you post the style?

Comment: Whats on line #18 in ur xml ?

Comment: Are you changing text in this textView? I often got stackoverflow when i change text when TextView has  onTextChanged. You should disable it before changing the text and then enable it after to prevent stackoverflow.

Comment: check the xml customview declaration whether is it linking to your animatedValueTextview or not
?

Comment: Line 18 is the very first line of the provided XML code

Comment: also you should avoid to post things like com.---.-----. This kind of errors can be lead also by words misspelling

Comment: sorry that is just my Work for this site... it isn't actually dashes :)

Comment: you did not get the point.

Comment: I have added the style now

Comment: in the real code the dashes (-) are letters as they should be.

Comment: I think Adam is on the right lines. When viewing in Eclipse under Graphical Layout, java.lang.StackOverflowError results (don't try this at home, it crashed my workbench...).

Comment: comment setText(valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue().toString()); line and run it again

Comment: okay.... but how do I disable it? I cant acces the enabled value from the code

Comment: When i comment the setText(valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue().toString()); line it works, but obviously not as supposed.

Comment: I have tried putting `setEnabled(false)` and `setEnabled(true)` arround the setText line without any luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another nice solution is not overriding the onTextChanged Method, and having two methods setText: A public one that will trigger the animation, and a private one that will change the value without animating:

```
private void init(){
    actualValue = 0;
    animator = new ValueAnimator();
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            setTextInternal(valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue().toString());
            actualValue = (Float)valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
        }
    });

    animator.setDuration(DURATION);
}


public void setNumber(float newValue){
    animator.cancel();
    animator.setFloatValues(actualValue, newValue);
    animator.start();
}

public void setText(String txt){
    try {
        float newValue = Float.parseFloat(txt);
        setNumber(newValue);
    }catch (Exception e){
        super.setText(txt);
    }
}


private void setTextInternal(String txt){
    super.setText(txt);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will definitly try your solution

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you are looping the setting of the text.

1) onTextChanged is called to save the initial value

2) The code in onTextChanged starts animating and in every step calls setText (which automatically will call onTextChanged)

3) This onTextChanged will cancel the animation and start it again.

The solution is to control by flag the calling of onTextChanged, add another listener to the Animation:

```
animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener(){
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
        isAnimating = true;
    }
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        isAnimating = false;
    }
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}
})


@Override
protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter) {
    if (isAnimating) return;
    super.onTextChanged(text, start, lengthBefore, lengthAfter);

    ...
}
```

Comment: You would still have to reset isAnimating after the animation ends, or it will only work once.

Answer (score 0):

In your `onTextChanged` method, you are starting the `animator`, which in turn calls `setText()` again, which in turn triggers `onTextChanged` again, which goes on forever, until the VM has enough.

If you change your `onTextChanged` method as follows, it works:

```
@Override
protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter) {
    super.onTextChanged(text, start, lengthBefore, lengthAfter);
    if (animator != null && (animator.isStarted() || animator.isRunning()))
        return;

    // rest as above
```

Comment: Is there a way to override the setText so I can use that in sted of OnTextChanged?